# Django giving error: NoneType is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server, django

I'm getting this error when I run the command `python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8002`:

```
Job "BackgroundClass.update_escalation (trigger: interval[0:01:00], next run at: 2023-07-18 14:18:08 UTC)" raised an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apscheduler/executors/base.py", line 125, in run_job
    retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
  File "/app/BackgroundClass.py", line 25, in update_escalation
    if len(requestall)>0:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 376, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1867, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 87, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1385, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mssql/compiler.py", line 223, in as_sql
    supports_offset_clause = self.connection.sql_server_version >= 2012
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mssql/base.py", line 465, in sql_server_version
    with self.temporary_connection() as cursor:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 694, in temporary_connection
    with self.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 323, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mssql/base.py", line 258, in _cursor
    conn = super()._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 299, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 282, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 263, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mssql/base.py", line 336, in get_new_connection
    connstr = encode_connection_string(cstr_parts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mssql/base.py", line 54, in encode_connection_string
    return ';'.join(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mssql/base.py", line 55, in <genexpr>
    '%s=%s' % (k, encode_value(v))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mssql/base.py", line 79, in encode_value
    if ';' in v or v.strip(' ').startswith('{'):
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

The error is telling me that The code `BackgroundClass.Update_Escalation` has a parameter `requestall` which is returning `None`. The code for BackgroundClass.Update_Escalation is:

```
class BackgroundClass:

    @staticmethod
    def update_escalation():
        startdate = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        enddate = startdate - datetime.timedelta(hours=2)
        Time_threshold = timezone.now()-timezone.timedelta(hours=2)
        logger.info(f"Got Time_threshold {Time_threshold} successfully")
        
        request_list=[]
        
        logger.info(f"Geting all escalation objects")    

        requestall=Escalation.objects.all()
        
        logger.info(f"Got all escalation objects")
        
        # if ((requestall is None) or (len(requestall) == 0)):
        #     logger.info(f"No escalation requests")

        if len(requestall)>0:
            for item in requestall:
                print(item)
                if update_status("%s" % item.request_id)==True:
                    request_list.append(item.request_id)
            logger.info(f"Got request_list with true {request_list} successfully")
```

requestall is basically a list of all objects: `Escalation.Objects` which is a class that holds the following details:

```
class Escalation(models.Model):

    field1= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    field2= models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS',blank=True)
    field3= models.CharField(max_length=255, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', blank=True,unique=True,null=False) 
    choices = [('R1', _('Executive/VP Request')), ('R2', _('Past Contractual SLA')),('R3', _('Billing Dispute'))]
    field4= models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=choices, blank=True)
    request_reason= models.CharField(max_length=255, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS', blank=True)
    field5 = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    field6 = DateTimeUTCField(auto_now_add=True)
    field7 = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS',default='open') #editable = False, 
    field8 = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    field9 = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS',null=True,blank=True)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request_level=='R1' :
            self.priority = 1
            self.request_reason = _('Reason1')
            super(Escalation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.request_level=='R2' :
            self.priority = 1
            self.request_reason = _('Reason2')    
            super(Escalation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.request_level=='R3' :
            self.priority = 2
            self.request_reason = _('Reason3')    
            super(Escalation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'uat_escalation' 
        verbose_name = _('Prioritized request')
```

I am not sure why requestall is returning None here. any advice is appreciated thanks!

Comment: You run a DB query on server start? That won't work generally, you have to change your approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should not use `mssql` but `mysqlclient` library. Upgrade it.

Also don't use `len()` for `queryset`'s, it's slower than using `.count()` (and it returns the same thing):

```py
if requestall.count():
   ...
```

You can try to check Django version too.